# How to make group in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have collection with documents like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"), "title" : "test title", "category" : "test category", "pubDate" : "1457599100", "code" : "ZZZ" },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"), "title" : "test 2 title", "category" : "test 2 category", "pubDate" : "1457599200", "code" : "ZZZ" }
```

How to make the grouping to get output something like this:

```
{
  "ZZZ": {
    "items": {
      0: { "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"), "title" : "test title", "category" : "test category", "pubDate" : "1457599100"},
      1: { "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"), "title" : "test 2 title", "category" : "test 2 category", "pubDate" : "1457599100"}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you similar to what you're looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $group : { _id : "$code", items: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }])
```

It will return:

```
{
  "_id" : "ZZZ",
  "items" :
     [
       { "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"), "title" : "test title", "category" : "test category", "pubDate" : "1457599100", "code" : "ZZZ" },
       { "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"), "title" : "test 2 title", "category" : "test 2 category", "pubDate" : "1457599200", "code" : "ZZZ" }
     ]
}
```

Documentation can be found [under $group aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).